# AttributeError: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an add-on with this code but keep getting this error. I've tried putting this line `obj = bpy.context.object` in `execute` but then i'll get another error wich i've sollved by putting this line outside of execute. Any help please?

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "test",
    "author": "Aziz",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Mesh",
}

import bpy

class ReducePolygons(bpy.types.Operator):
    
    bl_idname = "reduce.polygons"
    bl_label = "Reduce Polygons"
    obj = bpy.context.object

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DECIMATE')
        self.obj.modifiers["Decimate"].decimate_type = 'UNSUBDIV'
        self.obj.modifiers["Decimate"].iterations = 1
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(apply_as='DATA', modifier="Decimate")
        return {'FINISHED'}
       

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    
    bl_label = "test"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.label(text="Mesh Optimizations:")
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 2.0
        row.operator("reduce.polygons")
        

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ReducePolygons)
    


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ReducePolygons)
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I've tried putting this line `obj = bpy.context.object` in `execute` but then i get this error message on launch:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modifiers'
```

Also tried deleting this line `obj = bpy.context.object` and replacing `self.obj` with `context.object` as  Robert Gützkow suggested but unfortunately i got the same AttributeError.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112404/discussion-on-question-by-aziz-attributeerror-restrictcontext-object-has-no).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some edits**

Give operator a poll method so it requires an active object of type mesh (or a type that can have decimate modifier)

Add the modifier using the api method.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "test",
    "author": "Aziz",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Mesh",
}

import bpy

class ReducePolygons(bpy.types.Operator):
    
    bl_idname = "reduce.polygons"
    bl_label = "Reduce Polygons"
     
    @classmethod 
    def poll(cls, context):
        ob = context.active_object
        return ob and ob.type == 'MESH'
    
    def execute(self, context):
        ob = context.active_object
        dm = ob.modifiers.new(name="Foo", type='DECIMATE')
        
        dm.decimate_type = 'UNSUBDIV'
        dm.iterations = 1
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=dm.name)
        return {'FINISHED'}
       

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    
    bl_label = "test"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"
     

    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.label(text="Mesh Optimizations:")
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 2.0
        row.operator("reduce.polygons")
        

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ReducePolygons)
    


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ReducePolygons)
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot!